# Настройка Flask для отправки писем через доменную почту Яндекс

Tags: flask, яндекс-почта

Никак не могу правильно настроить сайт на flask, чтобы он отправлял письма через доменную почту Яндекса. Сама доменная почта настроена корректно, MX-записи есть, домен подтвержден и вообще все в ажуре. Но вот flask никак не могу подружить с ней. Вот код настройки:

```
MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USE_TLS = False
MAIL_USE_SSL = True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'info@*********.ru'
MAIL_PASSWORD = '*****************'
```

Comment: Что означает «не могу подружить»? Что делаете, как не работает, какой текст ошибки?

Comment: В данный момент при отправке тестового письма - smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить **MAIL_USE_TLS = True**, а MAIL_USE_SSL = True вообще убрать из конфига.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш config верен, все указанно правильно! Нужно изменить настройки почты с которой будет происходить рассылка('info@*********.ru'). Залогинтесь в яндекс почте('info@ *********.ru'),
перейдите в: Почта -> Все настройки -> Почтовые программы, и везде поставте галочки. Плюс нужно создать функцию для рассылки сообщений и указать в ней актуальные данные.
Пример:

```
def send_reset_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token()
    msg = Message('Запрос на сброс пароля',
                  sender='info@*********.ru',
                  recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body = f"""Чтобы сбросить пароль,
        перейдите по ссылке: {url_for('users.reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}.
    """
    mail.send(msg)
```